# Read back a saved LGBMClassifier model

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

I trained a LGBMClassifier model and saved in a file in this way:

```py
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier( ... )
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
clf.booster_.save_model("model1.txt")

##Predictions
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_data, num_iteration=clf.best_iteration_)[:, 1]
```

Now what I want is to use the saved model for another prediction. But if I do this:

```py
## new predictions:
clf_fs = lgb.Booster(model_file='model1.txt')
y_pred2 = clf_fs.predict_proba(X_data2, num_iteration=clf_fs.best_iteration_)[:, 1]
```

I got an error as

```
AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

I understand that `cls_fs` is an object of class Booster and not of a class LGBMClassifier, and that I can use `clf_fs.predict()`, but how I can get back a LGBMClassifier object from the saved booster file and all its specific attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Use `clf_fs.predict` instead.

[Reference link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4583)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/73181)